# Kubernetes loadbalancer stops serving traffic if using local traffic policy

Tags: networking, service, kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently I am having an issue with one of my services set to be a load balancer. I am trying to get the source ip preservation like its stated in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip). However when I set the `externalTrafficPolicy` to local I lose all traffic to the service. Is there something I'm missing that is causing this to fail like this?

**Load Balancer Service:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: loadbalancer
    role: loadbalancer-service
  name: lb-test
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.3.249.57
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: example service
    nodePort: 30581
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: loadbalancer-example
    role: example
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: *example.ip*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be several things. A couple of suggestions:

1. Your service is getting an external IP and doesn't know how to reply back based on the local IP address of the pod.

   - Try running a sniffer on your pod see if you are getting packets from the external source.
   - Try checking at logs of your application.
2. Healthcheck in your load balancer is failing. Check the load balancer for your service on GCP console.

   - Check the instance port is listening. (probably not if your health check is failing)

[image: lb]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by _running a sniffer_ however I checked the GCP console and it looks like some of my instances are unhealthily from the load balancer perspective. I'm not entirely sure how to resolve that but im looking into it now. Thank you.

Comment: sniffer can be something like tcpdump

Comment: so you can use tcpdump on the main interface of the pod/container and send it to a pcap file. After that you can copy it from the pod/container and analyze it with something like wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org/